# Spring - @Primary fails against @ComponentScan?

Tags: java, spring, testing, configuration, spring-test

For a simple POJO:

```
@Component
public class Foo
{
    private final String string;

    public Foo()
    {
        this("Secondary ComponentScan??");
    }

    public Foo(String string)
    {
        this.string = string;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return string;
    }
}
```

and this configuration

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = Foo.class)
public class TestConfiguration
{
    @Primary
    @Bean
    public Foo foo()
    {
        return new Foo("Primary bean!!");
    }
}
```

I would expect the following test

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = TestConfiguration.class)
public class Test
{
    @Autowired
    private Foo foo;

    @Test
    public void test()
    {
        System.out.println(foo);
    }
}
```

to print out `Primary Bean!!` but it returns `Secondary ComponentScan??` instead...

How come? Nowhere does the documentation for [@Primary](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.3.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Primary.html) say it fails against component-scanned beans!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The reason is that both beans actually have the same name `foo`, so internally one bean definition is getting overridden with the other one, essentially the one with `@Bean` is getting overridden by the one being scanned by `@ComponentScan`.

The fix is simply to give one of them a different name and you should see the correct behavior of the `@Primary` bean getting injected.

```
@Primary
@Bean
public Foo foo1()
{
    return new Foo("Primary bean!!");
}
```

OR

```
@Component("foo1")
public class Foo
{
..
```